# Laravel 5.5 PHPredis not working

Tags: php, laravel, redis, phpredis

I am fighting with phpredis + laravel 5.5. (PHP 7.2, nginx, ubuntu) The following code works well. That means the server is configured properly. Also the redis-cli works ok.

```
$redis = new Redis();
$con = $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->auth('password');   

$redis->ping();
```

This one:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
```

throws: *Call to undefined method Redis::connection()*

And this line:

```
Redis::set('name', 'Taylor')
```

throws: *Redis server went away*

I tried renaming the alias in config/app as some advice suggested, but it didn't help. Any idea, please?

Edit:
composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.7",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "intervention/image": "~2.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^4.0.2",
    "laracasts/utilities": "~2.0",
    "srmklive/paypal": "1.5.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
    "mews/purifier": "~2.0",
    "talvbansal/media-manager": "2.5",
    "roumen/sitemap": "^2.7",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1"

},
```

config/database.php:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'phpredis',

'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,

    ],

],
```

Comment: Please show your composer setting for the redis package you've installed. If it's not `predis/predis` blow away the one you're using and `composer require predis/predis`. Alternatively, you can change the `config name` from `predis` to `phpredis` in `config/database.php`, possibly.

Comment: I added a part of composer.json and config/databse.php

Comment: So, you've installed `predis` but you're referencing `phpredis` as the client. Just go ahead and change `'client ' => 'phpredis'` to `'client' => 'predis'` and you should be ready

Comment: And will that use the phpextension - phpredis? Or just the laravel package? Anyway, it didn't help.

Comment: It will use the package `predis`. I personally feel like there's a naming conflict going on here, Can you rename the facade in `config/app.php` to something other than Redis, like, `LaravelRedis` and see if that works?

Comment: I already played with this renaming, but still no luck.

Comment: Did you `composer dumpautoload` after renaming the Facade?

Comment: Yes, no change at all. Maybe I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I will keep experimenting.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have it. I was missing the RedisserviceProvider::class  line in the config\app.